# Get a binomial confidence interval for each row in a Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this with n binomial samples:

```
df<-data.frame(success=c(1,2,3,2),total=c(2,4,5,3))
```

Where I have to get a confidence interval for each row with the lowest value and the highest. Something like this: "0.25 - 0.39"

I would have to apply for each row the funcion binom.confint from "binom" library. But I am having some troubles to apply that function to each row.

If i could, I would need something like this to get the lowest, with the "exact" method:

```
a<-binom.confint(df$success[1],df$total[1],0.95)[5,5]
```

And something like this to get the highest:

```
b<-binom.confint(vpip$played[1],vpip$total[1],0.95)[5,6]
```

Then i would have to paste them into something like this with each row:

```
final<-paste0(a,"-",b)
```

There is any way to get the binom.confint function for each row, to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `binom.confit` is not vectorized that way. You can instead use a function like `mapply()` to call it once per row. For example

```
mapply(function(a,b) {
    paste(binom.confint(a, b, 0.95)[5, 5:6], collapse="-")
}, df$success, df$total)
# [1] "0.0125791170934251-0.987420882906575"
# [2] "0.067585986488543-0.932414013511457" 
# [3] "0.146632799634673-0.947255049473683" 
# [4] "0.0942993240502461-0.991596241340387"
```

You could use `round()` in there if you want fewer decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(binom)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(binom_test_var = list(binom.confint(x = success, n = total, method = c("exact")))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(binom_test_var)) %>% 
  mutate(merged_ci = paste0(lower, "-" , upper))
# # A tibble: 4 × 9
#   success total method     x     n  mean  lower upper merged_ci                           
#     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                               
# 1       1     2 exact      1     2 0.5   0.0126 0.987 0.0125791170934251-0.987420882906575
# 2       2     4 exact      2     4 0.5   0.0676 0.932 0.067585986488543-0.932414013511457 
# 3       3     5 exact      3     5 0.6   0.147  0.947 0.146632799634673-0.947255049473683 
# 4       2     3 exact      2     3 0.667 0.0943 0.992 0.0942993240502461-0.991596241340387
```